# AttributeError: str object has no attribute decode (python, ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, server

I've run a python file from the Ubuntu console and got an AttributeError. I'm not sure what's the problem.
Below is the code.

```
import threading
import json

from config.DatabaseConfig import *
from utils.Database import Database
from utils.BotServer import BotServer
from utils.Preprocess import Preprocess
from models.intent.IntentModel import IntentModel
from models.ner.NerModel import NerModel
from utils.FindAnswer import FindAnswer

# 전처리 객체 생성
p=Preprocess(word2index_dic='train_tools/dict/chatbot_dict.bin',
 userdic='../Tokenizing/user_dic.txt')

 # 의도 파악 모델
intent = IntentModel(model_name='models/intent/intent_model.h5', proprocess=p)

# 개체명 인식 모델
ner = NerModel(model_name='models/ner/ner_model.h5', proprocess=p)

def to_client(conn, addr, params):
    db = params['db']

    try:
        db.connect()  # 디비 연결

        # 데이터 수신
        read = conn.recv(2048)  # 수신 데이터가 있을 때 까지 블로킹
        print('===========================')
        print('Connection from: %s' % str(addr))

        if read is None or not read:
            # 클라이언트 연결이 끊어지거나, 오류가 있는 경우
            print('클라이언트 연결 끊어짐')
            exit(0)


        # json 데이터로 변환
        recv_json_data = json.loads(read)
        print("데이터 수신 : ", recv_json_data)
        query = recv_json_data['Query']
        # print(query) 여기 까지는 정상적으로 작동
        # 의도 파악
        intent_predict = intent.predict_class(query)
        intent_name = intent.labels[intent_predict]
        print(intent_name)
        # 개체명 파악
        ner_predicts = ner.predict(query)
        ner_tags = ner.predict_tags(query)

        # 답변 검색
        try:
            f = FindAnswer(db)
            answer_text, answer_image = f.search(intent_name, ner_tags)
            answer = f.tag_to_word(ner_predicts, answer_text)

        except:
            answer = "죄송해요 무슨 말인지 모르겠어요. 조금 더 공부 할게요."
            answer_image = None

        send_json_data_str = {
            "Query" : query,
            "Answer": answer,
            "AnswerImage": answer_image,
            "Intent": intent_name,
            "NER": str(ner_predicts)
        }
        message = json.dumps(send_json_data_str)
        print(message)
        conn.send(message.encode())

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("여기")
    finally:
        if db is not None: # db 연결 끊기
            db.close()
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':       # 다른 파일에서 import해서 쓰지 않고 여기서 실행할 때만 실행되는 구문

    # 질문/답변 학습 디비 연결 객체 생성
    db = Database(
        host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASSWORD, db_name=DB_NAME
    )
    print("DB 접속")

    port = 5050
    listen = 100

    # 봇 서버 동작
    bot = BotServer(port, listen)
    bot.create_sock()
    print("bot start")
    
    while True:
        conn, addr = bot.ready_for_client()
        params = {
            "db": db
        }

        client = threading.Thread(target=to_client, args=(
            conn,
            addr,
            params
        ))
        client.start()
```

I tried removing the str object, but the result did not change.
Below is a error-message.

> File "bot.py", line 17, in 
> intent = IntentModel(model_name='models/intent/intent_model.h5', proprocess=p)   File
> "/home/ubuntu/deepChatbot2/chatbot/models/intent/IntentModel.py", line
> 13, in **init**
> self.model = load_model(model_name)   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py",
> line 146, in load_model
> return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)   File
> "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 166, in load_model_from_hdf5
> model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8')) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Thank you.

Comment: Is this your issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44467

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I tried a lower version of h5py and it works.